# multibinding class properties into a column header and data

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, binding

Scenario:
I'm trying to bind an IEnumerable list of a custom class that consist of 3 properties: Date, Product and amount.
My listview/gridview is already set with all the columns that will change dynamically with the products that were manufactured.

The Problem:
Since I need to bind the data by the products that are also the columns I face a problem if I bind by the Product I won't see the amount and if I bind by the Amount I'll see it everywhere in the row.

Is there any option to multibind a column that will identify the product and then put the Amount in the cell?

This is the class I'm using:

```
    public class MonthlyProducts
{
    public string DateID { get; set; }
    public string ProductID { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}
```

I can't post the gridview code because it changes dynamically but this is where I'll need to put the multibind, I run over this code for every product:

```
    GridViewColumn TempColumn = new GridViewColumn();
    TempColumn.DisplayMemberBinding = ???;
    TempColumn.Header = item.ProductID;
    TempColumn.Width = 100;
    MonthlyGridView.Columns.Add(TempColumn);
```

I have to do it through the code since I'm building the listview everytime the client needs a report.
Also I don't need it to update as I saw people want to update the cells, I don't need that. this is for a report that the client will run and close the window after viewing the report.

Help me with this please, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should add two `GridViewTextColumns.`

Otherwise to your asked question, you set `MultiBinding` in [Code behind / ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5559900/649524).

Comment: I don't understand why ideally I'll need two Gridviewtextcolumns?